# Baking a Path Animation for Export, Deleting the Path

Tags: animation, export, path

I have seen in various online tutorials that it is possible to animate an object along a path (NURBS curve), bake the animation and then delete the path.

Each time I bake the animation and delete the curve, however, the object reverts to the center of the screen and loses all animation.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Below is an image of the object and the path:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed Visual Keying selection part.You need to select it, cause when you check Transforms for the object animated this way, it's position is actually not changing, so by baking action, you get only 2 frames - for start and the end animation and both have the same value. You need to bake visual transforms instead, then everything works. There are two ways to animate object along the path. One with parenting.Then this set of options needs to be selected for everything to work smoothly for baking action:[image] 
You are using second way, with use of constraint. Then you need also select Clear Constraints option.
[image]